# Why css selector :is() doesn't support pseudo elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I am trying to simplify the following code because the declarations within the three css rules are duplicated.

```css
input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #2196F3;
}
input::-moz-range-track {
    background: #2196F3;
}
input::-ms-track {
    background: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<html><head></head><body><input type="range"></body></html>
```

I realized that I can't use `,` to combine these selectors because it contains invalid selectors for a particular browser.

I used `:is()` but it doesn't work

```css
:is(input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, input::-moz-range-track,input::-ms-track){
    background: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<html><head></head><body><input type="range"></body></html>
```

`:is()` works fine with normal selectors and pseudo classes

but why css selector `:is()` doesn't support pseudo elements?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what your question is. That :is does not support pseudo elements is a fact (see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is). Are you asking why the creators of that standard decided pseudo elements weren't to be supported in :is? That seems like a question which is outside of the scope of SO.

Comment: @AHaworth   Well, I was previously reading the Chinese translation of that document and it is currently missing that fact.

Comment: That's unfortuate! I guess it's more reliable to go to the actual spec which says 'Pseudo-elements cannot be represented by the matches-any pseudo-class; they are not valid within :is().' (https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#matches-pseudo)

Comment: There's a highly technical discussion of the underlying reason at [Why "Pseudo-elements cannot be represented by the matches-any pseudo-class"?](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2284). Basically it comes down to a problem with the `::foo` notation.

Comment: @Alohci I think the problem here is the fact that each selector belong to a specific browser so any browser reading the whole selector will find at least an invalid one and will make the whole selector invalid (in addition to the fact that it's not support with pseudo elements)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - that applies to normal selector lists but not to forgiving selector lists, (as used in `:is()`) which is, I think, why the OP was trying to use `:is()`. So, strictly speaking, that issue lies outside the scope of this question.